# Oil and gas well symbology for geoserver

Tags: geoserver, point, symbology, oil-gas

I need to symbolise an oil and gas well dataset in geoserver.

I have the dataset symbolised in ArcMap using the standard esri well symbols. Is there an easy way to convert this esri layer file into an SLD? Or, is there some where I can reference well symbology in my SLD using an < ExternalGraphic>< OnlineResource xlink:href.../>??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reference the Esri ttf file that contained the well symbology I wanted using a mark operator and the unicode reference, see below;

```
          <PointSymbolizer>
     <Graphic>
   <Mark>
     <WellKnownName>ttf://ESRI Pipeline US 1#66</WellKnownName>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
   </Mark>
       <Size>20</Size>
     </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi again, As you suggested above the line with  <WellKnownName>ttf://ESRI Pipeline US 1#66</WellKnownName>  works well. However I could not figure out how to write correctly the font name "ESRI Oil,Gas, & Water". I tried writing as it was named in http://www.fonts2u.com/esri-oil-gas-water.font.  Though it did not work. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, at a guess I would say the issue is the '&' symbol (and possibly the commas as well) in the font name. I would try to find those symbols in a different font. Or you could look at creating your own font and copying those symbols in, I am not sure how easy/possible this is to do sorry. I'll investigate further and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Hi,I exported my sembolized layer as KMZ in arcgis and then unzipped the kmz file.
That gave me small png files accociated to my symbol representations.I moved those png files to my folder in Geoserver under 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.8.0\data_dir\workspaces" path.

Then  I used   

<Graphic>
<ExternalGraphic>
 <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="YourFolder/sembol.png" />
  <Format>image/png</Format>
</ExternalGraphic>
<Size>20</Size>
<Opacity>
   <ogc:Literal>1.0</ogc:Literal>
</Opacity>
</Graphic>
This works for now,Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Save the arcgis symbols as .Png format pictures in geoserver styles folder of data_directory. You can goto arcgis symbology directory and do that. Then provide that folder path in SLD for external graphic property. I don't see oil and gas symbols available for geoserver directly.

HARI

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the Shell fonts which are available. See [here](https://www.iogp.org/blog/geomatics/shell-releases-its-standard-legend-to-industry-and-academia/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
<sld:WellKnownName>ttf://ESRI Environmental &amp; Icons#41</sld:WellKnownName>
```